# Removing extra space inside div as screen becomes smaller

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, css-grid

Assuming that we have all padding and borders at 0px, I need to collapse a div to the minimum content possible, just enough to fit the text inside.
As the screen becomes smaller, the div will, as it should do, become smaller as well. Here's an example:

[Example one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJLUy.png)

In this example, the screen is at maximum size, and everything is fine.
As the screen gets smaller, in this second example below, the text, which is a div, breaks down predictably and preferably.

[Second Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cP3C4.png)

In this second example, I've colored in the sides I want to disappear and turn into a margin. To be clear,
I want the text to stay fixed in space I just want the width trimmed down more and the borders to be tight and flush with the text.

I'm working within a grid container; the div is in a grid container. I'm looking for the most minimal and easy CSS/HTML to implement, trying to avoid any JavaScript. While I do think it's possible without JavaScript, If I need to use it, I will.

I've tried changing the grid-column width. This could be the solution, as I might have done it incorrectly.
As has been said, I was wanting to remove the white space around the text, not the margin, nor the padding. It's the width. The "Existe" needs somewhere to go, and it goes below the other text, leaving extra space on each side.

Any response is appreciated, thank you.

Source code:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body, html {
    background-color: #212529;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;


    border-radius: 6%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #81a1c1;

    
     
    
    
    font-size: 90%;
    text-decoration: none;
}    

.header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr;
    
    grid-template-areas: "logo button-one button-two";
    
    grid-gap: 1%;
    
    
    margin-bottom: 1%;

    border: 4x;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #81a1c1; 

  
}



.logo {
    position: relative;
    grid-area: logo;
    justify-self: center;

    right: 20%;    
    font-size: x-large;

    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #81a1c1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button-one {
    grid-area: button-one;
    justify-self: end;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.button-two {
    grid-area: button-two;
    justify-self: center;
    font-weight: 600;
}


.main-content-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "text pic";
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;

}




.text {
    display: inline;
    grid-area: text;
    
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: center;
    

    font-size: 5em;
    color: #d8dee9;


  


    border: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #81a1c1;
    border-radius: 2%;

}   

.picture {
    grid-area: pic;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    
    


    border: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #81a1c1;
    border-radius: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nord</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <a class="logo" href="">Home</a>
            <button class="button button-one" >Contact!</button>
            <button class="button button-two">Email Me!</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="main-content-container">
        
        <!--<img class="content picture" src="nord.png" alt="nord-theme photo minimal white nord">-->
        
        
        <div class="content text">Lorem Ipsum<span style="color: #81a1c1;"> Existe</span></div>
        
    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try setting the with of this column to fit-content

Comment: It's very difficult to fix your code if you do not share it. Can you create a snippet into your question?

Comment: @LajosArpad I edited the question to include the source code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a media query like this one:

```
@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .text {
        font-size: 4em;
    }
}
```

to override your general rule. The `750px` was an arbitrary value, you can use yours instead. Also, you could create several such media queries and you can vary the `font-size` and `max-width` in order to fulfill your needs. An example is in this fiddle (I tested on a laptop screen, maybe you do not see it similarly, so I attach a screenshot)

[image]

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');

* {
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

body, html {
    background-color: #212529;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

.button {
    display: flex;
    align-items:center;
    justify-content:center;
    
    height: 40px;
    width: 80px;
    
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    padding: 0px;
    border: 0px;


    border-radius: 6%;
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #81a1c1;

    
     
    
    
    font-size: 90%;
    text-decoration: none;
}    

.header {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr 1fr;
    
    grid-template-areas: "logo button-one button-two";
    
    grid-gap: 1%;
    
    
    margin-bottom: 1%;

    border: 4x;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #81a1c1; 

  
}



.logo {
    position: relative;
    grid-area: logo;
    justify-self: center;

    right: 20%;    
    font-size: x-large;

    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    color: #81a1c1;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.button-one {
    grid-area: button-one;
    justify-self: end;
    font-weight: 600;
}

.button-two {
    grid-area: button-two;
    justify-self: center;
    font-weight: 600;
}


.main-content-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "text pic";
    
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;

}




.text {
    display: inline;
    grid-area: text;
    
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    
    text-align: center;
    text-justify: center;
    

    font-size: 5em;
    color: #d8dee9;


  


    border: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #81a1c1;
    border-radius: 2%;

}   
@media (max-width: 750px) {
    .text {
        font-size: 4em;
    }
}

.picture {
    grid-area: pic;
    align-self: center;
    justify-self: center;
    
    


    border: 4px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #81a1c1;
    border-radius: 2%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Nord</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div class="header">
            <a class="logo" href="">Home</a>
            <button class="button button-one" >Contact!</button>
            <button class="button button-two">Email Me!</button>
        </div>
    </header>
    <main class="main-content-container">
        
        <!--<img class="content picture" src="nord.png" alt="nord-theme photo minimal white nord">-->
        
        
        <div class="content text">Lorem Ipsum<span style="color: #81a1c1;"> Existe</span></div>
        
    </main>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a `max-width` property in your css or add a media query with the `max-width`.